# rnaturalearthhires package installation error

Tags: r

I am trying to install the `rnaturalearthhires` package but I am getting many errors.

Here is the first error:

```
Installing the rnaturalearthhires package.
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/kkost/OneDrive/Dokumenti/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
```

> Error in value[3L] :
> Failed to install the rnaturalearthhires package.
> Please try installing the package for yourself using the following command:
> `install.packages("rnaturalearthhires", repos = http://packages.ropensci.org", type = "source")`

Then I try the following code:

```
install.packages("rnaturalearthhires", repos = "http://packages.ropensci.org", type = "source")
```

And I get this:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:
https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/kkost/OneDrive/Dokumenti/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
**Error in install.packages : error reading from connection**
```

Then I try this code:

```
devtools::install_github("ropensci/rnaturalearthhires")
```

but end up getting this:

> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
> namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.8 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required

I also try this code:

```
install_github("ropensci/rnaturalearthhires")
```

But I get this:

> Error in install_github("ropensci/rnaturalearthhires") :
> could not find function "install_github"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this isssue, it might help:
https://github.com/ropensci/rnaturalearthhires/issues/2

```
install.packages("devtools") # I guess you also need this
devtools::install_github("ropensci/rnaturalearthhires")
library("rnaturalearth")
```

Answer (score 6):

devtools can take a looong time to compile and install for some users. installation directly from github can now be done with the remotes package.

`remotes::install_github("ropensci/rnaturalearthhires")`